# Kotlin - Two Pointer - Nested While loops causing: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, pointers, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

In the below code example, I'm trying to solve the [Longest Word in Dictionary Through Deleting](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-word-in-dictionary-through-deleting/) question on Leetcode. I think this solution should work, but for some reason the nested while loops below seem to break the function, and I can't figure out why.

The error I'm receiving is "Line 20: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1." With that said, I don't know how this error is happening at all when I have multiple checks to ensure this doesn't happen. Additionally, the wrapper for loop seems to be called more times than the number of indices in the dictionary.

The closest I found to figuring out what could be going wrong is by placing a println(i) at the top of the wrapper For loop, and commenting out the indicated While loops inside the wrapper Do - While loop.

When those inner loops are uncommented, the function seems to be on it's way to getting the answer, but for loop prints 0,1,2,3,0 and the function returns the error "Line 20: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1." When I comment out those loops, the function properly prints 0,1,2,3 and finishes returning an incorrect answer.

I have no idea why those loops are causing the wrapper For loop to run additional times from 0 and return that error of 1. Is that even the problem?

```
class Solution {
    fun findLongestWord(s: String, dictionary: List<String>): String {
        var answer = ""

        for (i in dictionary.indices) {
            
            // Printing i to test the iterations of function
            // Prints 0, 1, 2, 3 when below while loops are commented out
            // Prints 0,1,2,3,0 when the below two while loops aren't commented out.
            println(i)
            if (answer.length > dictionary[i].length) {
                
                continue
            }
            var tempString = s.toCharArray().toMutableList()
            
            var low = 0
            var dictLow = 0
            var high = tempString.lastIndex
            var dictHigh = dictionary[i].lastIndex
          
            do {
                // Commenting out the below two while loops causes function to work
                while (tempString.size >= answer.length && tempString.isNotEmpty() && tempString[low] != dictionary[i][dictLow] ) {
                    tempString.removeAt(low)
                    high -= 1

                }

                while (tempString.size >= answer.length && tempString.isNotEmpty() && tempString[high] != dictionary[i][dictHigh]) {
                    tempString.removeAt(high)
                    high -= 1
                }

                if (tempString.joinToString("") == dictionary[i]) {
                    var potentialAnswer = tempString.joinToString("")
                    if (potentialAnswer.length > answer.length) {
                        answer = potentialAnswer
                    } else if (potentialAnswer.length == answer.length) {
                        var list = mutableListOf(potentialAnswer, answer).sorted()
                        answer = list[0]
                    }
                    break
                }
                else {
                    low += 1
                    high -= 1
                    dictLow += 1
                    dictHigh -= 1
                }
                

            } while (tempString.size > answer.length && low < high) 
        }

        return answer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but here is something to check:

In

```
while (tempString.size >= answer.length 
&& tempString.isNotEmpty() && tempString[low] != dictionary[i][dictLow] ) {
```

the only part of this I think could raise `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is `dictionary[i][dictLow]`. You start `dictLow=0` and increment this later, but you have no guard condition, so inevitably, I presume, you will come across a String that has fewer characters than `dictLow`... hence the Exception

Comment: Thanks for your response AndrewL. As for the part you highlighted, that definitely could be an issue in some cases, however the question has the constraint: 1 <= dictionary[i].length <= 1000. So dictionary[i] will always have an index of 0.

What I'm trying to figure out is why those While loops cause the wrapping For loop to iterate through 0 again. I edited the question to include the exact values printed by "i" when they are included. 0,1,2,3,0 showing that it's looping again for some reason. When I remove the two while loops from the inner part, it properly loops 0,1,2,3.

Comment: (I still don't know what logic you are trying to implement!, but...) the two loops are not "symmetric" by which I mean while loop 2 references and decrements `*high` but loop 1 references `*low` but does not decrement `low` it decrements `high`.  Is this right?

Comment: So sorry let me describe the logic! The 's' variable is a string of letters. The dictionary is a list of strings. I'm supposed to return the longest string in the dictionary that can be formed by deleting some of the given string ('s') characters. I iterate over each string in the dictionary, and the while loops remove letters from the beginning and end of the 's' string until they find a letter in the current string. We reduce high in both cases because if we remove index 0, each letter is moved one index lower, so to reference the same character in high, we must decrement high...

Comment: If we remove a character on the right (high) side, we still need to decrement high simply to reference the next lowest character in the 's' string. Then we check to see if that string matches the current string in the dictionary. If so, we potentially set it as the answer if it's longer than the current answer. If it doesn't match the string in the dictionary, we increment low and high for both the 's' string to move on to removing the next letters that may not match the next two letters in the dict string. That's why dictlow and dicthigh also are incremented and decremented. Still unclear?